# Are Cassandra heartbeat requests costly?

Tags: java, cassandra

I am using the default heartbeat interval of 30 seconds. Has anybody experience any load issues using that default interval?

Comment: If it's a bad practice, why would they choose that as the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the number of reads your app does per given window. If you are sure that your app is going to keep knocking the database with queries then you can go with a longer interval or even disable it by setting it to 0. If you have a on and off kind of load pattern ( like your get request for 2mins and no request for 2 next two mins) then having the heart beat is critical in order to keep the connection active. Otherwise making a new connection would be costly.